# Глубокое обучение, как запустить проект?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, deeplearning4j

Читая статью https://medium.com/@akarshzingade/image-similarity... наткнулся на реализацию https://github.com/akarshzingade/image-similarity-deep-ranking Но там требуется скачать триплеты ( я это сделал) и заполнить вот это в (tripletSampler.py)

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Optional app description')

    parser.add_argument('--input_directory',
                        help='A argument for input directory')

    parser.add_argument('--output_directory',
                        help='A argument for output directory')

    parser.add_argument('--num_pos_images',
                        help='A argument for the number of Positive images per Query image')

    parser.add_argument('--num_neg_images',
                        help='A argument for the number of Negative images per Query image')
```

но я не понял как именно это сделать. подскажите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

argparse - это стандартный модуль Python. Он подробно описан в доке. В двух словах:

Этот модуль используется для анализа параметров командной строки разарабатываемой программы.

Метод *add_argument* добавляет аргумент в список возможных аргументов командной строки Вашей программы.

Параметр '--input_directory' указывает название ключевого параметра Вашей программы.

Прамаетр help='A argument for input directory' указывает, что будет печатаься в строке пояснения этого параметра, если вы введёте в командной строке:

```
python my_applcation --help
```